# Cloning CurrencyConverter 0.5 in Python to begin Installation Issue

Tags: python

I recently installed Python to be able to learn Python coding.  Using the links provided has helped at least to get started but I am hitting a wall.

I have tried the below code provided on the second link to try to install because I'm unaware about cloning in Python.

> $ pip install --user currencyconverter

Any help to get started to figure out the code on my own would be really appreciated.  Links I have been using to learn is below.

https://docs.python.org/3.6/tutorial/index.html

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/CurrencyConverter/0.5

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking for.  SO is for questions and help with code that you are working on.  If you have code, please post it.

Comment: The code in the quote box to which I thought was the Python code the second link was referring to would have been a starting point to ask for the code to install CurrencyConverter 0.5 in Python since that line isn't working.  Can you go into more details to what I need to provide?  I am new to Python and coding language in general.